# How to calculate the third control point of a Quadratic Bezier Curve?

Tags: math, graphics

I understand how to interpolate the position of the Bezier curves. But I am curious, how can I calculate the third control point if I only have two(2) control points (*Start & End*) and also the interpolated position of a Quadratic Bezier Curve. For example, if I only have **A** and **C**, how can I calculate the value of **B**.

See this picture:

[image: img].

I am looking for the value of the control point with the question mark.

I am asking this because I want to know how SVG editors archive something like:

[image: this image]

The red dot represents the value I am looking for. Hope I am making sense.

Comment: If you only have 2 points, don't you have a straight line?

Comment: There are an infinite number of points for B that would make the curve from A to C pass through a given point.

Comment: the missing point can be any ... it will just change the shape so you need more information to compute it exactly ... so what is known? for example derivations(slope) in A,C ?  or 3th point of the curve or what? if nothing than you can simply compute `B = (A+C)/2` and distort it a bit perpendicularly to `C-A` ...or randomly ...

Comment: I managed to find a solution to my problem here: http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/05/03/reverse-engineering-quadratic-bezier-curves/. Thnx to everyone who tried to help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quadratic Bézier curve can be best represented by the [De Casteljau's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm). That way, for a given `t` between `0` and `1`, a point `p` on the curve is defined as:

- a point `q` between `a` and `b`: `q = t*a + (1-t)*b`
- a point `r` between `b` and `c`: `r = t*b + (1-t)*c`
- then the point p is `r = t*q + (1-t)*r`

So, the Bézier curve is created by interpolating between points which on their turn are also interpolated. (Note that contrary to the first picture, your second picture doesn't use the same `t` for the 3 interpolations.)

In 2D, you have 2 equations for `p` (one for its `x` and one for its `y`). Suppose `a`, `c` and `p` are given. Then, you have 3 unknowns: `t` and the `x` and `y` of `b`.
Solving the equation would give `b = (a*t^2 + c*t^2 - 2*c*t + c - p)/(2*t*(t - 1))`. This means `b` can be anywhere on some complicated curve.  To fix `b`, you can choose some fixed value for `t`, for example `1/2`. Then, `b = 2*p - (a + c)/2`.

Other ways to restrict `b` could be suggesting that `p` is the furthest point on the curve. That would make `(q,r)` parallel to `(a,c)` and lead to slightly more complicated equations (`(rx - qx) * (cy - ay) == (ry - qy) * (cx - ax)`). Probably they need to be solved numerically.

Comment: This formula: ```B = 2*P - (A - C)/2``` answers my question. I forgot to mansion in my question that values for **P**; **A**; **C** and **t** are given

Comment: Probably you mean `B = 2*P - (A + C)/2` for the case where `t = 1/2`.  Another possibility is to choose `t = dist(A,P) / (dist(A,P) + dist(c,P))` which would take the relative distances into account.

Comment: I have tested your formula and it gives incorrect results. Please see this post: http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/05/03/reverse-engineering-quadratic-bezier-curves/. The correct way is ```B = 2*P - 0.5*A - 0.5*C```